# Error running socket.io on port 80 with Node.js in production

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io

I have been using node.js and socket.io for quite a while .

I have encountered a strange issue . In the past I used mostly long ports - 3000, 4001, 8888 etc for running my node and socket servers. I didnt face any issue .

However when I move the port to 80 , I get the following error -

**Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'**

I get this error only while running the page on Chrome . I am hosting this app on Amazon AWS. 
It works fine on localhost , but gives the error on production for port 80 .

I dont think this has anything to with my code, as it works on dev and non-80 ports.

Also I observe the socket communication falls down to xhr-polling and json-polling . While on non-80 ports , websockets work fine .

I am not sure whats the problem . I dont get the same error on other browsers , but the socket connections do not occur either.

I am not using nginx or any other load balancer.

Comment: Oh, but you are using AWS, which proxies your requests! This might be the reason (AWS proxy omitting `connection` header?). That's all I can say, because I don't have any experience with AWS.

Comment: So in that case why doesnt AWS Proxy my requests to other ports ( 3000, 8888) etc as well ?

Comment: Ports with numbers below 1024 are privileged (you need root privileges  to use them). So it might be a security issue. Remember that cross-domain policy **does not** apply to WebSockets (thus it makes sense to block WebSocket calls in some cases)! That's the only idea I have. Good luck!

Comment: I run the service as root. Hence I do not suspect any privilege issues .

Comment: It doesn't matter. The issue is not with you. The issue is with AWS proxying requests. Or at least I do believe so. Try contacting them and ask them about that. If it is not that then, then again: I cannot help you. One more time: good luck! :)